# Validating nicedit form textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a form which is transformed to rich text editor by Nicedit. Also i have applied Jquery validation plugin to the form and everything works fine except the textarea tag. 
 The textarea tag is not responding to the jquery validation plugin. When i click on the submit button without entering text into the textarea, the form gets submitted. I will be very glad if someone could help me.
 Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="nicEdit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body
{
font-family:Gotham,'sans-serif';
}

    </style>
    </body>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="ruebenform" novalidate="novalidate">
    Firstname: <input name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <textarea id="thetextarea" rows="5" cols="45"></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        new nicEditor({maxHeight : 50}).panelInstance('thetextarea');
    </script>

    //Jquery validation script
  <script>
    $("#ruebenform").validate({
                rules:{
                         firstname: {
                                 required: true,
                                 minlength: 2
                         },
                         thetextarea: {
                                 required: true,
                                 minlength: 2
                         }
                 },
                 messages: {
                         firstname: {
                                 required: "Please enter a title",
                                 minlength: "At least 2 characters"
                         },
                         thetextarea: {
                                 required: "Please enter a description",
                                 minlength: "At least 2 characters"
                         }
                 },
                 submitHandler: function(form) { return false; }
         });
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an ID to the textarea. Then just call it with jQuery, and check the length and apply the css rules.